# Swift I have four textfields and one submit button, how can I make the button active only when all textfields have a string

Tags: swift, uibutton, ios8, uitextfield

The problem with my code is that the user will have to click away
from the fourth field to a different field for the submit button to
become active again I am new to stackoverflow and new to the swift programing language any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
@IBOutlet weak var enterPlayer1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var enterPlayer2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var enterPlayer3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var enterPlayer4: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var submit: UIButton!


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
{       
     if enterPlayer1.text != "" && enterPlayer2.text != "" && enterPlayer3.text != "" && enterPlayer4.text != "" 
     {    
         submit.enabled = true
     } else {
         submit.enabled = false
     }

     return true         
 }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    enterPlayer1.delegate = self
    enterPlayer2.delegate = self
    enterPlayer3.delegate = self
    enterPlayer4.delegate = self

    submit.enabled = false

    //submit.enabled = false
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding the following UITextViewDelegate method instead

```
optional func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool" UITextFieldDelegate method instead:
```

So basically,

```
override func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> BOOL
{
    if enterPlayer1.text != "" && enterPlayer2.text != "" 
       && enterPlayer3.text != "" && enterPlayer4.text != "" 
    {        
        submit.enabled = true
    } 
    else 
    {
        submit.enabled = false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I just did and it still has the same effect. the user will have to click to a different textfield when he is done with the fourth textfiled for the code to run

Comment: OOPS, sorry.. I just updated my post. Basically this will check the text fields every time there is an edit.. I hope this works better!

Comment: perfect!!!! thank you so much I've been trying to do it on my own for two days now. This is exactly what I want

Comment: the only thing i noticed is that the last textfield will have to have at least two characters for the button to become active again

Comment: Given that the text isn't actually changed at the moment this method is called, this isn't really the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

We need to look at the text field after its text has finished changing.  None of the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods actually call back to the delegate for an event like "didChangeCharacters".

Instead, we can create an `IBAction` for this.

[image]

Right click on one of your text fields to get the pop-up menu pictured in the screenshot.  Click and drag from the "Editing Changed" circle into your view controller class to create the method.

Now you can click and drag from the same spot for the other text fields, but with the others, rather than creating a new method, hook them into this method.

When you've hooked everything up, your outlets might look something like this:

[image]

Most importantly here is seeing all four text fields hooked into the Received Actions.  I called my method "textChanged" for this example.

Now, just write your validation code.  In this case, the following "textChanged" method would work:

```
@IBAction func textChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    self.button.enabled = self.field1.text != "" && self.field2.text != "" 
        && self.field3.text != "" && self.field4.text != ""
}
```

Though strictly speaking there's a decent chance that this exact validation will crash as `UITextField`'s `text` property can be `nil`.

Comment: I tried your approach but I'm back to the same problem where when I'm done with field 4 I have to click to a different field for the button to be active

Comment: Make sure to hook up all text fields with the correct action.

Comment: I did I even made a new project with just the four textfields and one button. the button does not enable as soon as you start entering text.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather put it into the action like this :

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(){
if(enterPlayer1.text == "" ){
    myBool = NO
}
if(enterPlayer2.text == ""){
    myBool = NO
}
if(enterPlayer3.text == "" ){
    myBool = NO
}
if(enterPlayer4.text == ""){
    myBool = NO
}

if (myBool){
    //Rest of code here
}
```

}

Comment: ok but if I start typing text in the bottom field the button gets enabled

Comment: Okay so rather calculate the length of the player name with countElements(enterPlayer1.text) > (whatever you want to set it as)